# Create column based on another one but without matching alphabetically

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I created a column of names like this
df:

```
   PC
1  word
2  Now
3  Hate
4  Look
5  Check
```

I want to create another column based on this one and I was able to do that by

```
df<- df %>%
     mutate (PCcode= factor [letters(PC)])
```

However, the new column assigned letters alphabetically which I do not want! I need to assign letters from A-Z but based on the order in the column to be like this:
df:

```
   PC     PCcode
1  word     A
2  word     A
3  Hate     B
4  Look     C
5  Check    D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` + `unique` to get unique index based on the occurrence of the value.

```
transform(df, PCcode = LETTERS[match(PC, unique(PC))])

#     PC PCcode
#1  word      A
#2  word      A
#3  Hate      B
#4  Look      C
#5 Check      D
```

If you prefer to do it in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(PCcode = LETTERS[match(PC, unique(PC))])
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PC = c("word", "word", "Hate", "Look", "Check"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```